# backpropogation in convolutional neural network

Tags: python-3.x, statistics

1)  Please correct my understanding: Feed forward neural network and CNN will only learn weights and go a forward pass, it will not update the weights by comparing the error between actual and predicted value using backpropogation?

2)  If I want to use the backpropogation method in CNN, what step I need to include?

3)  If backpropogation is not possible in CNN, how can I update the weights?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry that you did not get an earlier response, but for future reference:

1) A CNN is a type of feedforward NN. It does not update the weights unless you train it

2) Here is a good explanation on how to implement it: https://becominghuman.ai/back-propagation-in-convolutional-neural-networks-intuition-and-code-714ef1c38199

3) It is possible

Comment: Thanks for the link, got it